# Extending `axvspan` to the Border of A Plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have the following dataset:

```
# Make the data
df = pd.DataFrame({'weight': [200, 170, 160, 150, 145],
  'days': [0, 91, 174, 205, 279]})
​
# Display the data
df
weight  days
0   200 0
1   170 91
2   160 174
3   150 205
4   145 279
```

I want to make a `lineplot` with `avxspan` with the following code.

```
# Plot
sns.lineplot(
        x=df['days'],
        y=df['weight'],
        marker="o",
        alpha=0.5)
plt.axvspan(200, max(df['days']), facecolor='g', alpha=0.4, label='Intermittent Fasting Starts')
plt.xlabel('Days Passed')
plt.ylabel('Total Weight (Lbs)')
plt.legend();
```

[image: The Plot:]

However, the span isn't going to the extreme of the plot border.

How can I make the span to the edge of the plot?

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `plt.xlim(right=max(df['days']))`?

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you @BigBen!